# BUAgent backup agent using 4GB of memory when not running - Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu

A BUAgent program installed on one of our servers looks to be using 4GB of memory. The server only has 8GB. BUAgent only runs out of hours to backup the site anyway.

Running htop you get the following...

[image]

Our network has another running the same agent and it's taking a tiny amount of memory. The directory where this agent is installed shows it weighting in at 65MB.

I'm wondering if I understand what I'm seeing here? Is it really taking up 53% of available RAM? Is there something I can do to understand what is taking up all the memory? Am I correct in understanding that my machine has to operate with only 4GB now since BUAgent is sitting there hogging the other 4GB?

I'm not supposed to need to stop the service when it's not running.

Comment: Any logs you can check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this means that BUAgent is consuming 53.8% of your memory. The resident memory `RES` column also confirms this: 4294 MB. Your machine is left with the remaining memory. After that, it will start using swap.

The reason could be (I don't know about this program):

- a memory leak (BUG in the software).
- different configuration causing it to use more memory.

If it is not increasing with time, it may be acceptable to keep it running if your machine does not need more than the remaining memory.

Anyway, you can try to look for possible BUG/memory leak to fix this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the memory issue by simply restarting buagent. It's part of a service called vvagent in my case.

Run the following to get status information about both services...

`$ service vvagent status`

And then stop and start the service as normal with...

`$ sudo service vvagent restart`

This cleared the memory and it has successfully ran the backup program since without memory usage jumping back up.